# Не выводится кириллица при формировании pdf com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10

Tags: android, kotlin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как включить поддержку кириллицы при формировании pdf-файла с помощью библиотеки `com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10`?

Пробовал по-разному, никак не работает:

```
     /*      val bf = BaseFont.createFont(
               Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN.name,
            //"/font/times_new_roman_xml.xml",
              BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,
             // "",
            BaseFont.EMBEDDED
        )
        //val font: Font = Font(bf, 30F, Font.NORMAL)
        val font = Font(bf, 14F, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)*/
        // Table
        val table = PdfPTable(5)
```

// Header

```
        val FONT_HEADER = FontFactory.getFont(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN.name, 14F, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        val bfTimes =
            BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false)

        val times:Font = Font(bfTimes, 12F, Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.RED)

        mDoc.add(Paragraph(mText,times))


        var cell1 = PdfPCell(Phrase( "  1 Ступень фыв фыв " ,times))
        var cell2 = PdfPCell(Phrase("machi asd asd ds 2 ddf nes",times))
```

Comment: Может быть [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005077/1380933) ответ вам поможет?

Comment: Спасибо, видел это решение уже , стоит внимательно читать )
Это помогло!